# Download URL for latest Python version

Tags: python, download

I need a way to download the latest Python version using a script. With Selenium and Python it wouldn't be a big effort, but I need Python first.

Are there URLs similar to those from [Firefox](https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest-ssl&os=win64&lang=de) or [FileZilla](https://download.filezilla-project.org/client/FileZilla_latest_win64_sponsored-setup.exe)?

Or another simple way with native tools from Linux and Windows?

Comment: Do you mean something like `wget`? And here is a link to the [Python download page](https://www.python.org/downloads/).  Just find the URL to the version you’re after and pop that into `wget`.

Comment: No. I would like to have the possibility to download the latest release at any time. Whether I do this with wget, curl or WebClient request is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

This is the link for direct download of Windows executable:

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.4/python-3.8.4.exe

For Linux, the link is:

https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.8.4/Python-3.8.4.tgz

Comment: This is the current version. But when I run the script in a month it still downloads 3.8.4 although 3.9 was released.

Comment: I’m not sure if this exists for Python, but I know Miniconda offers a ‘latest’ installer script.  See here for [Linux](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh) and here for [Windows](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda2-latest-Windows-x86_64.exe). The links will download the latest scripts.  The [full repo](https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/) can be found here.